# In VSCode when exporting functions: "Individual declarations must be all exported or all local"

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I recently upgraded to Visual Studio Code 0.5.0 and some new errors cropped up that weren't there before.

I have a bunch of functions that are declared locally and then exported. Since the upgrade, however, hovering over each of the local function names produces the error **Individual declarations in merged declaration *functionName* must be all exported or all local.**

This is an example local function that is exported.

```
var testParamsCreatorUpdater = function (lTestParams, creatorID){
    lTestParams.creator = creatorID;
    return lTestParams;
};
module.exports.testParamsCreatorUpdater = testParamsCreatorUpdater;
```

I realize I can change this to...

```
module.exports.testParamsCreatorUpdater = function (lTestParams, creatorID){
    lTestParams.creator = creatorID;
    return lTestParams;
};
```

And prepend **module.exports.** to every **testParamsCreatorUpdater()** call.

But why is the first snippet wrong? As I understand it, require() makes everything in the module.exports object available to whatever required it.

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue in Webstorm , I Restarted it and it went away

Answer (score 5):

I think at a JavaScript level it cannot differentiate between:

```
var testParamsCreatorUpdater = ...
```

and

```
module.exports.testParamsCreatorUpdater = ...
```

as the names are the same. I got the exact same error (leading me to this post) in TypeScript when I tried this:

```
import { AuditService } from '../services/audit.service';
import { Audit } from '../models/audit.model';

@Component({
    selector: 'audit',
    templateUrl: './audit.component.html',
})
export class Audit {
    constructor(private auditService: AuditService) {
    }
}
```

So TypeScript did not like that I imported a module called **Audit** and exported a class also called **Audit**.

Answer (score 1):

You are exporting a variable in this file which is imported in the same file module (locally).

Comment: this is what the previous developer was doing so doing this now as well

Answer (score 1):

So DuckDuckGo got me here searching for the exact same error, but in 2022. I didn't find the exact reason so posting as an update and for completeness.

---

```js
import { Something, SomethingElse } from './some/path';
import { ref } from 'vue';

// Many lines of code

function doTheStuff() {
  // The declarations were previously just local variables ...
  // const Something = ref<Something>();
  // const SomethingElse = ref<SomethingElse>();
}

// ... but then I decided to export them and got the error
export const Something = ref<Something>();
export const SomethingElse = ref<SomethingElse>();
```

You simply can not import `Something` as a type and then export `Something` variable as a value of a kind (here a vue reference object). However, you *can* name a local variable the same name as the type, like I originally had. It is the import/export combination where things got broken. Solution for me was to locally rename the types:

```js
import { 
  Something as SomethingType, 
  SomethingElse as SomethingElseType
} from './some/path';
import { ref } from 'vue';

// ...

// No naming conflict anymore
export const Something = ref<SomethingType>();
export const SomethingElse = ref<SomethingElseType>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's related to the feature of merged declaration for TypeScript [ref](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html). I have not done the detailed research for Typescript but it seems that it can include Javascript in the Typescript file.

I guess the way testParamsCreatorUpdater was declared in the Javascript was detected to be error by VSCode because it thinks the two declarations cannot be merged.

Comment: Any update on this?  I'm also getting this err in VS2017 update 3 w the a module that declares 3 interfaces.

Comment: It's not a VScode problem. Your TS compiler will give you the same error.